# how to import the parent model on gae-python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, model, parent

```
main:.
├─a
│     ├─__init__.py
│     └─aa.py
├─b
│     ├─__init__.py
│     └─bb.py
└─cc.py
```

if i am in aa.py , how to import cc.py ?

this is my code ,but it is error :

```
from main import cc
```

what should i do .

thanks

**updated**

in normal python file (not on gae),i can use this code :

```
import os,sys
dirname=os.path.dirname
path=os.path.join(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0,path)
import cc
print cc.c
```

but on gae , it show error :

```
ImportError: No module named cc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how the code you've shown can possibly be failing for you.  Trying to reproduce your problem, I built the following pared-to-the-bone project:

```
$ ls -lR
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff    0 Jun 10 21:20 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 aleax  staff  136 Jun 10 21:28 a
-rw-r-----@ 1 aleax  staff  107 Jun 10 21:27 app.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff   21 Jun 10 21:20 cc.py
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff  471 Jun 10 21:25 index.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff   75 Jun 10 21:20 main.py

./a:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff    0 Jun 10 21:20 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff  130 Jun 10 21:20 aa.py
```

Here are the nonempty Python files:

```
$ for f in main.py cc.py a/aa.py; do echo "File: $f"; cat $f; echo; done
File: main.py
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'in main'
from a import aa

File: cc.py
print 'in cc'
c = 23

File: a/aa.py
import os, sys
dirname=os.path.dirname
path=os.path.join(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0,path)
import cc
print cc.c
$
```

It runs just fine, as predicted, showing (both when run locally on the SDK and when run on google's servers at appspot.com):

```
in main
in cc
23
```

So there must be some other error in parts of your code that you're not showing us.  Please confirm this by reproducing this tiny project and trying it both locally and on appspot.com and let us know how it works (or fails...?) for you.